# Change scope of .each loop with drop-down bar (Rails 3.2, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

In my app I have a modal with the following code:

```
  .modal-body
    .row
      .col-sm-4
        .btn-group-vertical#gear-buttons-list
          - Gear.all.each do |gear|
            .btn.btn-large.btn-default.gear-button{"data-id" => gear.id} #{gear.name} ($#{gear.charge})
```

I am making a list of buttons that have the name of charge of a piece of Gear for the user to select. However, elsewhere on the page there is a drop-down bar that lets the user select a Category. In my app, a Category has_many Gears, and I would like the modal to display only the Gears that are associated with the Category that has been chosen, such as the following scoped defined in Gear.rb:

```
scope :moving, -> { where(category_id: 1) }
```

Is there a straight-forward way to code the .each loop in the modal so that it is scoped dynamically based on the selected Category?

This is what I have tried in `jobs.js` (after changing it to `jobs.js.erb`):

```
  if($('#job_category_id').length > 0) {
    $('#job_category_id').change(function() {
      var categoryID = $(this).val();  
      var categoryName = _categories[categoryID].name;
      $("#gear-buttons-list").html("");   // clear default buttons
      $("#gear-buttons-list")            // append new buttons
        .append("<% Gear." + categoryName + ".each do |gear| %><div class='btn btn-large btn-default gear-button' "data-id" => gear.id><%= #{gear.name} %></div><% end %>");
    });
```

This doesn't work, apparently because of the way I'm trying to do string concatenation in the embedded Ruby (getting `syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG` error). Can someone perhaps point me in the right direction with this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update the page (fetch it again from the server), or at least the fragment with gears each time a category changed. Right now you're trying to execute Ruby code in the browser, which obviously won't work.

Comment: What is "obvious" is different for each developer, since we all have different amounts of knowledge and experience. At any rate, it turns out I can use Ajax to avoid having to update the page each time a category is changed (which was probably 'obvious' to many people besides us! ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using Ajax:

1) I make the following Ajax request in `jobs.js` (categoryID is derived from an earlier call to `val()`:

```
$.ajax("/gears", {dataType: "script", data:{category_id: categoryID}})
```

2) In `gears_controller.rb`:

```
def index
    @gears = Gear.where(category_id: params[:category_id])
end
```

3) The controller renders the Gear index, which is `.js.erb`, which in turn renders a collection partial with one button for each Gear:

```
/views/gears/index.js.erb

$("#gear-button-list").html("<%=j render partial: '/gears/gear_buttons', collection: @gears, as: :gear %>")
```

4) The partial:

```
.btn.btn-large.btn-default.gear-button{"data-id" => gear.id} 
  %p 
    %h5 
      #{gear.name} ($#{gear.charge}) <br />
      %small #{gear.description}
```